# What's an opaque field?

Tags: com, terminology

What is an opaque field?  This term is used a lot in the definitions of IAz... interfaces, e.g in [IAzOperation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa377899.aspx), it says:

```
ApplicationData   Read/Write   Sets or retrieves an opaque field that can be
                               used by the application to store information.
```

There are many such similar defs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's one whose value is meaningful to the client but not the library, or vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Opaque means Private. Nothing else can read/write to it. Similar to private in OOP, and the synonym is "transparent", where anything can read it.